# How to register my custom app in linux ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to add a c++ program as a terminal app in linux. How to register my app so that it can be run from anywhere in my computer's terminal?

I am using ubuntu.

Comment: add it location to path forr example

Comment: Place it somewhere `PATH` can find it, like `/usr/bin`

Comment: Register it as an environment variable by editing it. See this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables) on how to edit environment variables. After that, try running it from any directory on your computer.

Comment: Another cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297458/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-anywhere-on-my-server

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environment variable named `$PATH` that specifies a set of directories where executable programs are located:

1. Save your binary in an adequate directory such as `usr/opt/your-app`;
2. Using the `export` command, append the above directory to the `$PATH` environment variable;
3. Invoke your binary through the terminal.